# Why is load greater than effort in a machine if its velocity ratio is more than 1?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, velocity

I read it in my grade 10 book that if velocity ratio of a machine is more than 1, it acts as a force multiplier. Can someone elaborate how are the magnitudes of load and effort related to the velocity ratio which is defined as the ratio of velocity of effort to velocity of load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have heard about the concept of *Work*. Work is the currency of mechanical energy and for a machine the work going in must equal to work coming out (since energy isn't created).

Work $W$ is defined as a Force $F$ applied though a parallel displacement $\Delta x$ as $$ W = F \,\Delta x$$

The speed at which work is applied or extracted is called power $P$, and it is related to the above as $ P = F \,v$ where $v$ is the speed at which the displacement $\Delta x$ is transversed.

Since at any point in time work-in equals work-out, it means that at any moment power-in equals power-out.

$$ F_{\rm in} v_{\rm in} = F_{\rm out} v_{\rm out} $$

Now you can work out the above is a specific kinematic relationship between speeds is given, how it will constraint the ratio of forces.

Comment: **Ah I see, so-**

 _(Fᵢₙ/Fₒᵤₜ) = (Vᵢₙ/Vₒᵤₜ)_
and since _Vᵢₙ_ is more than _Vₒᵤₜ_ (if _VR_ >1) we can say that _Fₒᵤₜ_ is more than _Fᵢₙ_ (or to make things clearer,  _Load_ is more than _Effort_) since they are in proportion. Hence, the machine acts a force multiplier.

Thank you, and correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: **_Since at any point in time work-in equals work-out, it means that at any moment power-in equals power-out._**  Does it mean that we can prove a machine as a force multiplier if its velocity ratio is greater than 1 only in an ideal situation? By ideal I mean no loss of the input energy due to friction.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: @JavaMonke - As long as the machine does not store energy, only to be released later, like a spring or flywheel. If the power flow is direct and immediate then the mechanical advantage is directly derived from the speed ratio. **NOTE** I said speed and not velocity, because it is the component of velocity parallel to the force that matters only here.

Comment: alright, and thank you so much